# Design LQR controller with zero value for the matrix of system

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

In design controller for a first order system such as:
$$\dot{x}=-ax+bu$$
they assume that value of $a>0$. I need to know is it possibile to neglect this assume an design the controller even if  $a=0$ as same as if $a>0$ ?

In other words can I design LQR for this system with $a=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a = 0$ and $b \neq 0$ you can take

$$
u = -\frac{k}{b}x \tag{1}
$$

with $k > 0$, so your dynamics $\dot{x} = b \, x$ will be

$$
\dot{x} = -k \, x
$$

Because you can choose $k$ freely (only needs to be positive), you can realize *any* stable linear 1st order dynamic with $(1)$. So yes, you can use LQR in that case.

Answer (score 1):

[LQR](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lqr.html#f3-254493) only requires from the system that you are trying to control that the pair $(a,b)$ is stabilizable (assuming you choose appropriate weights $Q$ and $R$). For this scalar case this means that $b\neq0$ (when $a\leq0$). So when $b\neq0$ then $a$ could be anything, also negative.

It can be noted that LQR does assume that you have perfect knowledge of the system, so know the exact values of $a$ and $b$. If you do not know $a$ exactly then for $a<0$ the closed loop system might be unstable.